# Loading image from url ios 8 objective c

Tags: objective-c, url, ios8, photo

i´m trying to obtain the imagen from this url[@"file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0158.JPG"], but i can´t.
Always is nil.

this is my code:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: @"file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0158.JPG"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
self.pruebaTmp.image = image;
```

i obtain the url with this code:

```
    if (asset) {
        // get photo info from this asset
        PHImageRequestOptions * imageRequestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
        imageRequestOptions.synchronous = YES;

        [[PHImageManager defaultManager]
         requestImageDataForAsset:asset
         options:imageRequestOptions
         resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI,
                         UIImageOrientation orientation,
                         NSDictionary *info)
         {
            NSURL *path = [info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"];
             //asignamos el path de la imágen seleccionada en galeria
            self.pathImagen = path;
         }];


    }
```

if someone could help i would be very grateful, because i can´t load the image with the url obtained.

Comment: I imagine that you don't have permission to access to that path, if it even exists.

Comment: frist thanks for answer me.how can i obtain permission?

Comment: I would verify that is the problem.  You can use `NSFileManager` to try and list the contents of the folder.  Pay attention to the error parameter.  Once you've verified it, give up.  There's no way to request permissions for such things.  Where did you get this path from, anyway?

Comment: i´m trying to obtain the photo`s url from gallery, and then save the url for opening it again the photo later. at this time, i´m trying to opening the url.

Comment: OK.  You need to go through the photo gallery API to access photos.  You can't access them by directly, through the filesystem.

Comment: to acces gallery i use: - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info.   and it´s from here where i obtain the url. is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

you can`t not get UIimage or metadata from that url. 
you can get UIImage from local Identifier of access

```
PHFetchResult *savedAssets = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:@[localIdentifier] options:nil];

[savedAssets enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    //this gets called for every asset from its localIdentifier you saved
    //PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat
    PHImageRequestOptions * imageRequestOptions = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    imageRequestOptions.synchronous = NO;
    imageRequestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast;
    imageRequestOptions.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast;
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager]requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:imageRequestOptions resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
        NSLog(@"get image from result");
        if (result) {          

        }

    }];
    imageRequestOptions = nil;
}];
```